# On start-up of google tv, show live tv? Start service on boot?

Tags: startup, google-tv

I am pretty new at android development and am working on an android app for google tv. my current hurdle is that i want to start the Live TV app as soon right after the GTV starts.

I am thinking that it would be a Service that loads on startup that tells the Live TV app to start, but i don't know if a Service at startup is possible, nor do i know how to target the Live TV app.

any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A user can set the startup application from the UI.  If setting LiveTV to be the startup app isn't enough (it's the default), you can have your app start, then launch Live TV.

You can also have services that start at launch do it, just as you can on any Android platform.

Comment: Ah, I see now. The default application was set to 'None'. I see now how to launch Live TV application at start up.

What i need is something along your second comment. I want to start my service first, set some things up with the service, and then launch the Live TV app.

how do i start the Live TV app from code?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to make LiveTV be the start up application (Set up in the Google TV UI). Then, I set my service to start on boot, explained here.

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/